# Find all the functions satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all real x,y

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Hint:You may need order properties and completeness of real numbers.

My solution :

We can prove that $f$ will be a continious function and so

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

Now taking the limit $h\rightarrow0$, we get

$$f'(x)=a$$
Where $a=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$

Solving the differential eqaiton we get

$$f(x)=ax+c$$

As $f(0)=0$ we can get $c=0$

And the function satisfing the first condition are $f(x)=ax$ where $a$ is a constant.

Also $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$, then

$$(ax)(ay)=a(xy)$$
$$\implies a^2=a\implies a=0,1$$

Therefore the functions are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=x$.

My solution is very informal.

The problem: I wnat to write the solution formally , I don't think that I will be able to write my solution formally as I have assumed differentiability of $f$ and also I haven't used the hint and I found this problem in a UG textbook where derivatives are not yet introduced so I was thinking how to solve it without using derivtive and kind solve from scrach, Please help!!!!!!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may wish to read up on [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: The issue with your proof is that you haven't actually shown that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$ exists. The correct way to solve this is to note that $f$ must be order-preserving and must be linear on $\mathbb{Q}$, which allows you to show that $f$ must be continuous. We know that either $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, or $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$; continuity allows us to extend this to all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @prets Note that $x \leq y$ iff $\exists z (x + z^2 = y)$. Therefore, if $x \leq y$, then take $z$ such that $x + z^2 = y$; then $f(x + z^2) = f(x) + f(z^2) = f(x) + f(z)^2 = f(y)$. Therefore, $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

Comment: @Mark Saving but how will you do that?

Comment: @mrxking To prove $f$ is order-preserving, see my comment. Once you've done this, note that because $f(1)^2 = f(1^2) = f(1)$, we have either $f(1) = 1$ or $f(1) = 0$. Prove by induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f(n) = n \cdot f(1)$. Extend this to all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then extend again to all $n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thanks for you help